# α versus β D-ribopyranose

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I understand that sugars are named α/β according to the arrangement of the OH on the anomeric C with respect to the hydroxymethylene group (Ex. glucose), but I'm a little confused how you determine α/β when you don't have that group (Ex. ribopyranose, below).

[image: α-D-ribofuranose] 
α-D-ribopyranose

[image: β-D-ribofuranse] β-D-ribopyranose

Thanks!

Comment: Draw the compound in its linear form.

Comment: @Joel I don't see how that would matter? It's the same exact compound in it's linear form...

Comment: Yes it is but it's easier to determine its isomerism in its linear (straight chain ) form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not the hydroxymethelene group that determines the α/β status of a sugar, instead it's the relative orientation of the anomeric hydroxyl to the stereocenter which determines the absolute stereochemistry (D/L) of the sugar. This just so happens to match up with the same side/opposite side heuristic for the common six carbon pyranoses, but that's a quick rule of thumb, not the official definition:

> **α (alpha), β (beta)**: Relative stereodescriptors used in carbohydrate nomenclature to
>   describe the configuration at the anomeric carbon by relating it to
>   the anomeric reference atom. For simple cases the anomeric reference
>   atom is the same as the configurational reference atom. Thus in
>   α-d-glucopyranose the reference atom is C-5 and the OH at C-1 is on
>   the same side as the OH at C-5 in the Fischer projection.

[IUPAC Gold Book](http://goldbook.iupac.org/A00003.html)

> The configuration at the anomeric centre (that derived from the
>   carbonyl carbon) is denoted alpha- (α-) or beta- (β-) by reference to
>   the stereocentre that determines the absolute configuration. In a
>   Fischer projection, if the substituent off the anomeric centre is on
>   the same side as the oxygen of the configurational (D- or L-) carbon,
>   then it is the α--anomer. If it is directed in the opposite direction
>   it is the β-anomer.

[CAZypedia](https://www.cazypedia.org/index.php/Anomeric_centre_(alpha_and_beta)) - includes diagrams and examples, including for five carbon pyranoses.